# Clause after "Than" in comparatives?

Tags: grammar, comparative-constructions, comparative

Can I use a clause after *Than*?

> You are better than *when you were yesterday.*
>
> People have more chances of dying when they don't fasten their seatbelts than *when they do*.
>
> You're faster than *I am*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use clauses after "than". Your last two examples are fine.
 You first example doesn't work, though. You could say

> "You are better than you were yesterday."

Comment: You are better today than (you were) yesterday. Doesn't it work this way too?

Comment: @RamPillai Yes, it works that way too.